# Saving/getting preferences using java.util.prefs.Preferences causes BackingStoreException

Tags: java, exception, preferences, store

After declaring

```
private static Preferences systemPrefs = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage (SomeClass.class);
```

, either one of these lines of code:

```
String someString = systemPrefs.put("someKey", "someValue");

String someString = systemPrefs.get("someKey", "someDefaultValue");
```

causes this error, which repeats itself over and over during the rest of the
program execution:

`java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
VARNING: Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: /etc/.java/.systemPrefs/edu create failed.`

I suspect there is some kind of security issue somewhere.

Could it be that this problem is specific to this computer for some reason? Could there
be some other reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `root` privileges to update the system-level preferences. Normal users should only be able to update user-level preferences.

Comment: I tried changing the first line to this:
`private static Preferences systemPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(SomeClass.class);`
and all worked well =). Thanks!